# Convert int to time

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in that date and time has given separate and time is given in int format .I have to merge date and time column in date time format like dd:mm:yyy hh:mm:ss.this merge value should insert in "MergeDT" column that is required output.
I already mentioned output in MergeDT column.

```
ID | DATE_TAKEN            |    TIME |         MergeDT            |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2005-08-01 00:00:00   |    702  |   2005-08-01 07:02:00      | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2  | 2005-08-01 00:00:00   |    702  |   2005-08-01 07:02:00      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------      
3  | 2005-08-01 00:00:00   |    702  |   2005-08-01 07:02:00      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
4  |  2003-01-22 00:00:00  |    1603 |   2003-01-22 16:03:00      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
5  |  2005-08-01 00:00:00   |   702  |   2005-08-01 07:02:00      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
6  |  2005-08-01 00:00:00   |   3    |     2005-08-01 00:03:00    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------  
7  |  2005-08-01 00:00:00   |   504  |   2005-08-01 05:04:00      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
8  |  2003-01-22 00:00:00   |   1646 |   2003-01-22 00:00:00      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Pls put your code here..

Comment: What is the value of time field? If it is amount of seconds from the beginning of day - then you can just use `dateadd` with `ss` datepart and update your MergeDT column.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta which code?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev its not seconds .its like 703 will be 07:03:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be something along these lines:

```
UPDATE UnnamedTable SET MergeDT = DATEADD(hour,  [time] / 100,
                                  DATEADD(minute,[time] % 100,DATE_TAKEN))
```

---

Re: confusing *data* and *representations*. The datetime data types in SQL Server store the data in a compact binary representation. They don't store any formatting information. I don't think anyone would be surprised that the following:

```
declare @t int
set @t = 0x0D
print @t
```

Prints `13` rather than `0x0D`, and yet people seem to be perpetually surprised that the same logic applies to the datetime types - they stored the *data*, in a single consistent format, rather than storing the string representation that was used to set their value.

Comment: I tried your query, it is very near to solution.like for 702 it is giving now 07:02:00.0000000 .i need only 07:02:00

Comment: @vim - what's the data type for `MergeDT`? If, as it should be, it's a `datetime2` column, then this is correct. What's stored is a *binary* representation of a datetime value that management studio will convert into a *string* when it's *showing* the data, and by default management studio does that conversion to include all of the trailing zeros. Don't confuse the *data* (what is stored) with a *representation* (what is shown to you). No *formatting* information is stored with the data.

Comment: Datatype is Time for MergeDT

Comment: So, again, the behaviour is correct. `date`, `time`, `datetime`, `datetime2` - all of these store the *data* in a compact binary format. They *don't* store strings.

Comment: your solution is perfect only I need to trim extra zeros.

Comment: I don't know how else to say this. Those zeros *don't exist* in the data that is stored in the database. They only exist when the data is being *retrieved* and something (like the output grid in SSMS) decides to convert the data into a string. If you want a particular format, you have to do the conversion yourself when you *retrieve* the data.

Answer (score 0):

converting the time in integer format (generally seconds) to time in sql server is as follows.

```
declare @t int
set @t = 110

select cast((@t / 60) as varchar(2)) + ':' + cast((@t % 60) as varchar(2))
```

Comment: that is not in seconds .its like 702 that means 07:02:00

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correclty you needs something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT( DATETime, SUBSTRING(DATE_TAKEN, 0, 10) + ' ' + select cast(([TIME] / 100) as varchar(2)) + ':' + cast(([TIME] % 100) as varchar(2)) + ':00')
```